# Running function on window scroll once in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window

I'm creating my portfolio and I'm trying to make my skill bars load when I go to "My skills" section. I want them to do it only once, either when someone scroll to this section or goes to it straight away from the navigation. This is my code:

```
var skills = $('#mySkills');
  var skillsPositionTop = skills.position().top;
 $(window).on("resize scroll", function (){
      if (pageYOffset<skillsPositionTop-20 && pageYOffset>skillsPositionTop-80){
    console.log ("here is my loading script");
```

}
    });

It doesn't work when I use `one` instead of `on`, doesn't work when I created one more function on window with `one` inside my if statement.
I was trying exit the function with `return` or `return false` as well and here, on stack overflow I found something about flag, which I didn't fully understand but I tried different combinations with it.
Can someone please help me with it? I've seen there is a library for this type of effects, but there is no point of installing any just for one thing...

Edit. Console.log represens my loading code.

Comment: Is requirement to call `console.log("here is my loading script");` at most once?

Comment: this code is quite long so instead of copying it here I used this console.log to show it as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a namespace at `.on()` for `resize`, `scroll` events, use `.off()` within `if` statement to remove namespaced events.

```
var skills = $('#mySkills');
var skillsPositionTop = skills.position().top;
$(window).on("resize.once scroll.once", function (){
  if (pageYOffset<skillsPositionTop-20 && pageYOffset>skillsPositionTop-80) {
    $(this).off("resize.once").off("scroll.once");
    console.log ("here is my loading script");
  }
});
```

Comment: @Sara Note, [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) call could be adjusted to `.off(".once")`